# Plotting the normal and binomial distribution in same plot

Tags: r, plot, distribution, normal-distribution

As the title indicates I am trying to plot the normal distribution and the binomial distribution in the same plot using R. My attempt can be seen below, is there any reason why my normal distribution looks so off? I have double checked the mean and standard deviation and everything looks fine.

[image]

```
n <- 151
p <- 0.2409

dev <- 4
mu <- n*p
sigma <- sqrt(n*p*(1 - p))

xmin <- round(max(mu - dev*sigma,0));
xmax <- round(min(mu + dev*sigma,n))
x <- seq(xmin, xmax)
y <- dbinom(x,n,p)

barplot(y, 
     col = 'lightblue',
     names.arg = x,
     main = 'Binomial distribution, n=151, p=.803')

range <- seq(mu - dev*sigma, mu + dev*sigma, 0.01)
height <- dnorm(range, mean = mu, sd = sigma) 
lines(range, height, col = 'red', lwd = 3)
```

Comment: It is because barplot and lines don't have the same abscissa : https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/231876.html

Comment: @cbo So how do I fix it? =) I need to vary `p` and `n`, so I would like to avoid having to manually adjust my normal distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`barplot` is just the wrong function for your case. Or if you really want to use it, you'd have to rejigger the x-axes between `barplot` and `lines`

The default for `barplot` is to put each `height` value at

```
head(c(barplot(y, plot = FALSE)))
# [1] 0.7 1.9 3.1 4.3 5.5 6.7
```

This can be changed by your choices of `space` and `width` or a combination of both

```
head(c(barplot(y, plot = FALSE, space = 0)))
# [1] 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5

head(c(barplot(y, plot = FALSE, space = 0, width = 3)))
# [1]  1.5  4.5  7.5 10.5 13.5 16.5
```

You can just use `plot` to avoid dealing with those things

```
n <- 151
p <- 0.2409

dev <- 4
mu <- n*p
sigma <- sqrt(n*p*(1 - p))

xmin <- round(max(mu - dev*sigma,0));
xmax <- round(min(mu + dev*sigma,n))
x <- seq(xmin, xmax)
y <- dbinom(x,n,p)

plot(x, y, type = 'h', lwd = 10, lend = 3, col = 'lightblue',
     ann = FALSE, las = 1, bty = 'l', yaxs = 'i', ylim = c(0, 0.08))
title(main = sprintf('Binomial distribution, n=%s, p=%.3f', n, p))
lines(x, dnorm(x, mean = mu, sd = sigma), col = 'red', lwd = 7)

xx <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 1000)
lines(xx, dnorm(xx, mean = mu, sd = sigma), col = 'white')
```

[image]

The "bars" in this figure depend on your choice of `lwd` and your device dimensions, but if you need finer control over that, you can use `rect` which takes a little more work.

```
w <- 0.75
plot(x, y, type = 'n', ann = FALSE, las = 1, bty = 'l', yaxs = 'i', ylim = c(0, 0.08))
rect(x - w / 2, 0, x + w / 2, y, col = 'lightblue')
lines(xx, dnorm(xx, mean = mu, sd = sigma), col = 'red', lwd = 3)
title(main = sprintf('Binomial distribution, n=%s, p=%.3f', n, p))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ggplot2` package

```r
library(ggplot2)

n <- 151
p <- 0.2409
mean <- n*p
sd <-   sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
binwidth <-   0.005


xmin <- round(max(mu - dev*sigma,0));
xmax <- round(min(mu + dev*sigma,n))
x <- seq(xmin, xmax)
y <- dbinom(x,n,p)

df <- cbind.data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = 'dodgerblue3')+
  labs(title = "Binomial distribution, n=151, p=.803",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme_minimal()+
  # Create normal curve, akousting for number of observations and binwidth
  stat_function( 
    fun = function(x, mean, sd, n, bw){ 
      dnorm(x = x, mean = mean, sd = sd)
    }, col = "red", size=I(1.4),  
    args = c(mean = mean, sd = sd, n = n, bw = binwidth))
```

[image]

Comment: Rlover removing `* n * bw` makes it fit perfectly

Comment: awesome, I've edited my answer to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the `ggplot2` package (I was surprised by the normal distribution but replacing geom_line by geom_point convinced me that is has this form (is the variance too high ?)) :

```r
n <- 151
p <- 0.2409

dev <- 4
mu <- n*p
sigma <- sqrt(n*p*(1 - p))

xmin <- round(max(mu - dev*sigma,0));
xmax <- round(min(mu + dev*sigma,n))

x <- seq(xmin, xmax)
y <- dbinom(x,n,p)

z <- dnorm(x = qnorm(p = seq(0,1, length.out = length(x)), mean = mu, sd = sigma), mean = mu, sd = sigma)

library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
data.frame(x, y, z) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = y)) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = z, colour = "red"),
          show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the shape so different from what the OP has? Also as an aside, you've loaded `magrittr` just to get the pipe operator, which isn't needed if you just use the data frame as the first argument to `ggplot` directly

Comment: 1) That is because of the variance formula used (it was an incorrect one). 2) I believe showing a non tidyverse user the pipe operator the right thing to do as addition to ggplot use (literate programming).